# Custom geolocation search resolver using aws-amplify api

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-amplify

I'm trying to add a custom geolocation search resolver that targets an Elasticsearch domain using aws-amplify API ([base on documentation](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli/graphql#add-a-custom-geolocation-search-resolver-that-targets-an-elasticsearch-domain-created-by-searchable))

My Custom stack json is :

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "An auto-generated nested stack.",
    "Metadata": {},
    "Parameters": {
        "AppSyncApiId": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Description": "The id of the AppSync API associated with this project."
        },
        "AppSyncApiName": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Description": "The name of the AppSync API",
            "Default": "AppSyncSimpleTransform"
        },
        "env": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Description": "The environment name. e.g. Dev, Test, or Production",
            "Default": "NONE"
        },
        "S3DeploymentBucket": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Description": "The S3 bucket containing all deployment assets for the project."
        },
        "S3DeploymentRootKey": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Description": "An S3 key relative to the S3DeploymentBucket that points to the root\nof the deployment directory."
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "QueryNearbyUsers": {
            "Type": "AWS::AppSync::Resolver",
            "Properties": {
                "ApiId": {
                    "Ref": "AppSyncApiId"
                },
                "DataSourceName": "ElasticsearchDomain",
                "TypeName": "Query",
                "FieldName": "nearbyUsers",
                "RequestMappingTemplateS3Location": {
                    "Fn::Sub": [
                        "s3://${S3DeploymentBucket}/${S3DeploymentRootKey}/resolvers/Query.nearbyUsers.req.vtl",
                        {
                            "S3DeploymentBucket": {
                                "Ref": "S3DeploymentBucket"
                            },
                            "S3DeploymentRootKey": {
                                "Ref": "S3DeploymentRootKey"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "ResponseMappingTemplateS3Location": {
                    "Fn::Sub": [
                        "s3://${S3DeploymentBucket}/${S3DeploymentRootKey}/resolvers/Query.nearbyUsers.res.vtl",
                        {
                            "S3DeploymentBucket": {
                                "Ref": "S3DeploymentBucket"
                            },
                            "S3DeploymentRootKey": {
                                "Ref": "S3DeploymentRootKey"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "Conditions": {
        
    },
    "Outputs": {
    }

}
```

But It give me this error :

```
Resource Name: QueryNearbyUsers (AWS::AppSync::Resolver)
Event Type: create
Reason: No data source found named ElasticsearchDomain (Service: AWSAppSync; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NotFoundException; Request ID: 920993d8-46ef-11e9-82c8-e977f5face03)
```

I tried many different things for `DataSourceName` including the domain name in aws console  or copy pasting the code from other auto generated stacks,... unfortunately none of them work .

How can I find `DataSourceName` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, there is a typo in their documentation and it should be :

```
"DataSourceName": "ElasticSearchDomain",
```

not :

```
"DataSourceName": "ElasticsearchDomain",
```

now it's working fine.. so many hours wasted on such a simple typo.